# I need to implement delete option using react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am getting this error:
Invalid value of type object for mergeProps argument when connecting component Home.
Tried to resolve by removing fetchData from connect(), but unable to resolve.
Can you please help me with this.
Here is link to my code.

Home Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class Home extends React.Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        console.log('ppp');
        this.props.deleteVehicle(this.props.home.id);
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchData();
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.props.onUnload();
    }

    render() {
        //console.log(this.props);
        const vehiclesItems = this.props.home.map((vehicle, index) => (
            <tbody key={}>

            </tbody>
            ))
        return (
            <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr className="table-heading">
                        <th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Year</th><th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>



            </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    home: state.home.items,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({

});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, { fetchData })(Home);
```

Comment: Please show us some code ,

Comment: Instead of giving a link to your whole code base, could you just include snippets of relevant code like your Home component and your connect().

Comment: I also tried removing fetchdata from connect and called through mapDispatchToProps  function but the data is not loading.

Comment: Were you able to reach the console.log inside handleClick and deleteVehicle functions after removing fetchData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked at your code again and found the problem. The problem lies in the way some functions are being called. This includes the fetchData function and the handleClick function.

Here's the solution I found (I ran the code from the link you provided and it works):

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { REMOVE_VEHICLE } from '../../constants/actionTypes';
import VehicleList from '../VehicleList';
import { fetchData } from '../../constants/postActions';

class Home extends React.Component {

    handleClick = (e,id) => {
        console.log('ppp');
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.deleteVehicle(id);
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('mounted');
        this.props.fetchData();
    }

    render() {
        //console.log(this.props);
        const vehiclesItems = this.props.home.map((vehicle, index) => (
            <tbody key={vehicle.id}>
                <tr key={vehicle.id}>
                    <td> {vehicle.model} </td>
                    <td> {vehicle.make} </td>
                    <td> {vehicle.year} </td>
                    <td> <button onClick={(e)=>this.handleClick(e,vehicle.id)}>Delete</button> </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            ));
        return (
            <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr className="table-heading">
                        <th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Year</th><th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                    {vehiclesItems}

            </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    home: state.home.items,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    deleteVehicle: id => dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_VEHICLE', id: id}),
    fetchData: ()=> dispatch(fetchData())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Answer (score 0):

Think, in spec, mergeProps is a function that receives several params like:

`mergeProps(mapStateToPropsValues, mapDispatchToPropsActions, yourProps) => //can return object with redux props and merged with your own ones`

Additonal info about it: https://medium.com/mofed/reduxs-mysterious-connect-function-526efe1122e4

Also in your case you can add fallback with flag on load and toggle it when data will dispatched on page